# SFTP slow with high latency

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, tcp, sftp

Server has a 1Gbps uplink speed, local PC has a download speed of 100Mbps. Latency is 89ms.

SFTP speed while downloading a single file from the server to the PC maxes out at 2.5MB/s, even though higher throughput can be achieved when downloading multiple files simultaneously.

Answer (score 2):

After tuning the [TCP window size](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-tcp-tuning/) on my server to be higher than the [Bandwidth Delay Product](https://www.speedguide.net/bdp.php), I was still getting low download speed from my local PC.

Windows 7 uses a default TCP window size of 16MB, but there is a bug that causes TCP Window Scaling to run in "restricted" mode due to Windows "heuristics" being enabled. The solution is to [disable heuristics](https://www.duckware.com/blog/how-windows-is-killing-internet-download-speeds/index.html)

After doing so, SFTP speed from the server to local PC (89ms RTT) instantly went from 2.5 MB/s to 11 MB/s